# How to create alerts in Splunk programmatically through a Python script?

Tags: splunk

I'm trying to write a Python script that takes user input and sends and creates the alerts in Splunk. Is this something that has been done before?

Answer (score 0):

An alert in Splunk is just a saved search with an action associated with it.  So, to create an alert you just have to create a search and give it the desired action.  Then when the search runs and the triggering condition is detected, the alert action will fire. The alert happening is based on something being found in the data, not on an external event.

There is no programmatic way to tell Splunk "send this as an alert".

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding. I have created a few alerts in Splunk and understand how they work. What i'm trying to do is create an automated way for alerts to be created based on information people give me, so they're not manually creating it themselves. The closest thing that I have found is Splunk's Rest [API](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/RESTREF/RESTsearch#alerts.2Fmetric_alerts), but i'm looking for something like creating alerts through HEC tokens.

Comment: HEC is for ingesting data, not for management.  The API and SDK are your only options for creating alerts programmatically.